# 802.11 Sniffer Capture Analysis deauth packets with wireshark

Tags: linux, wireshark, wifimanager, wifi

I'm trying to analyse my Sniffer Capture and to get information about the STA, who sends deauth packets. Actually I'm doing it with my laptop and my AP to test my WLAN security

```
        aireplay-ng [wlan inteface] --deauth 1000 -a {BSSID}
```

But where in this wireshark capture should I look for the MAC Adress from the station who sends deauth packets (my laptop)? All I can see here, it's like my AP sends packets to himself. Maybe it's a silly question, but I do not get it.

[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You send deauth to broadcast if command is used like this:

```
 aireplay-ng [wlan inteface] --deauth 1000 -a {BSSID}
```

When this command is running from the laptop, packets will be sent with the AP address of the point specified in the "-a" option:

Source address = Transmitter Address = AP BSSID

Explanation of addresses:

- Receiver Address: immediate recipient of the frame
- Destination Address: final recipient of the data
- Transmitter Address: STA that transmitted the frame
- Source Address: source of the data

Answer (score 0):

So in case if you don't get it let me tell you why you're seeing deauth packets are getting send from your own mac address to you mac address because if you are using aircrack-ng tool than what it does by default it changes the mac address of the sender with the station or the access point in which deauth packets are going to get send. You can think it
as an extra step ahead for security if you want you can also mention your mac address but for this see the '--help' options in there you will find by which option you can mention your mac address.